# Lebesgue Dominated THeoerm for integrals (mostly pre-algebra question)

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone check these for me?

> Justify passing the limit into these integrals.
>
> 1. $\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1 +x^2)} dx$
> 2. $\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1+nx^2}{(1 + x^2)^n} dx$
>
> 3 $\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x/n)}{(1 + (x/n))^n} dx$

1. I said that the first integrand $\dfrac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1 +x^2)} \leq \dfrac{n \sin(x/n)}{x} \to 1 $, for large $x$.
2. For $n \geq 1$, and $x \in(0,1)$, $\dfrac{1+nx^2}{(1 + x^2)^n} \leq \frac{n}{2^n} \to 0$
3. I want to say this is dominated by $0$, but I got no justification.

(**EDIT**: Actually, I just realize, I think the above is bounded by $1/e$)

Comment: You need absolute values in 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the first case, you need to find a dominating function which is actually integrable. Your dominating function is not integrable: it has a logarithmic divergence at both $0$ and $\infty$. A good approach is to note $|\sin(x/n)| \leq |x/n|$, so your function is dominated by $\frac{n \frac{x}{n}}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Looking at the second case, use binomial expansion to see that for sufficiently large $n$, the denominator grows like $1+n^2x^4$ or something similar.

Looking at the last case, use binomial expansion to see that for sufficiently large $n$, the denominator grows like $1+x^2$ or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 3: Show $1+x^2 \le 4(1+x/n)^n$ on $[0,\infty)$ for $n>1.$